# unity 5.5 - OnMouseClick not fired

Tags: unity, c#, bounding-boxes

On the Unity Editor, the `OnMouseClick()` function is fired but in my executable file it does not work. It is rare for it to fire, but it does not fire when the object is clicked. I have tried to:

The method used:

```
public void checkHit()
{
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
    {
        Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
        RaycastHit hit;
        if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit))
        {
            if (ammo > 0)
            {
                money++;
                explosion.Play();
                health -= dmg;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

- Set a BoxCollider2D
- Set a BoxCollider

None of these methods have worked so far when opening the game from the executable file.

This is my code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

[RequireComponent(typeof(AudioSource))]

public class SeAI : MonoBehaviour {

    public Image sof;
    public Canvas Game;
    public Canvas GameOver;
    public Canvas WinScreen;
    Vector3 canvasMin;
    Vector3 canvasMax;
    Vector3 randomVec;
    System.Random r;
    public Text ammoTxt;
    public Text moneyTxt;
    public Text outOfAmmo;
    public Text gunDmg;
    public Text seLife;
    public Button addDmg;
    public AudioSource explosion;

    int ammo = 10;
    int money = 0;
    int dmg = 1;
    int health = 250;

    void Start()
    {
        GameOver.enabled = false;
        WinScreen.enabled = false;
        canvasMin = Game.GetComponent<Collider2D>().bounds.min;
        canvasMax = Game.GetComponent<Collider2D>().bounds.max;
        randomVec = new Vector3();
        r = new System.Random();
    }

    void updateScore()
    {
        ammoTxt.text = "AmMo: " + ammo;
        moneyTxt.text = "MoNeY: $" + money;
        gunDmg.text = "Gun Damage: " + dmg;
        se.text = "Se's Health: " + health;
        addDmg.GetComponentInChildren<Text>().text = "Add gun damage: $" + (dmg * 2);
    }

    public void buyAmmo()
    {
        if (money > 1)
        {
            ammo += 6;
            money -= 2;
        }
    }

    public void addGunDamage()
    {
        if(money >= (dmg * 2))
        {
            dmg += 1;
            money -= (dmg * 2);
        }
    }

    public void checkHit()
    {
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
            RaycastHit hit;
            if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit))
            {
                if (ammo > 0)
                {
                    money++;
                    explosion.Play();
                    health -= dmg;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    void checkClicks()
    {

        if (Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0))
        {
            if (ammo >= 1)
            {
                --ammo;
            }
        }
    }

    void checkGameOver()
    {
        if((money <= 1) && (ammo == 0))
        {
            Game.enabled = false;
            WinScreen.enabled = false;
            GameOver.enabled = true;
        }
    }

    void checkWin()
    {
        if(health <= 0)
        {
            Game.enabled = false;
            GameOver.enabled = false;
            WinScreen.enabled = true;
        }
    }


    public void tryAgain()
    {
        SceneManager.LoadScene("Game");
    }

    public void Quit()
    {
        Application.Quit();
    }

    void Update ()
    {

        checkHit();
        updateScore();
        checkClicks();
        checkGameOver();
        checkWin();

        if(ammo < 1)
        {
            outOfAmmo.enabled = true;
        }
        else if(ammo > 0)
        {
            outOfAmmo.enabled = false;
        }

        if(r.Next(0, 30) == 15)
        {
            randomVec.x = r.Next((int)canvasMin.x, (int)canvasMax.x);
            randomVec.y = r.Next((int)canvasMin.y, (int)canvasMax.y);

            gameObject.transform.position = randomVec;
            sof.transform.position = randomVec;
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this issue by adding a Collider2D to the image, then I checked to see if the mouse position was inside of the Collider2D bounds when the image is clicked on. I also had to move the Collider2D to where the image was moving.

Example:

```
public void checkHit(){
    if(Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)){
        if(sof.transform.GetComponent<Collider2D>().bounds.Contains(Input.mousePosition)){
            //Code here
        }
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if `SeAI` script is enabled and attached to an active gameObject in the scene `Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)` should work. otherwise it shouldn't.

if `SeAI` script is enabled and attached to an active gameObject in the scene, and also it it a raycast target and no other raycast targets are blocking the raycast to it, then `OnMouseClick` should work. otherwise it shouldn't.

[image]

If you must use `OnMouseClick` make sure your game object with SeAI script, has a component which provides the raycast ability and no other (probably invisible) raycasts targets are in front of it.

Note 1 - colliders are also raycast targets.

Note 2 - raycast hits only one target.